# Linux - find if folder change time is greater than 2 hours

Tags: linux, directory

How can I check if some folder have been changed in last 2 hours?
Something like:

```
# pseudo code
if find folder_name -cmin +120
    echo "Folder content is updated"
```

In my root directory I have these directories:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 User1  Group1  4.0K May 24  2013 current_archive
drwxrwxr-x 8 User1  Group1  4.0K Aug 21  2014 CELLS
drwxrwxr-x 2 User1  Group1  4.0K Aug 27  2014 TESTORA
drwxrwxr-x 5 User1  Group1  4.0K Jul 10  2017 TEST
drwxrwxr-x 8 User1  Group1  4.0K Sep 26 11:11 CVBS
drwxrwxr-x 7 User1  Group1  232K Sep 26 12:15 SMSC
drwxrwxr-x 7 User1  Group1   36K Sep 26 12:45 SGW
drwxrwxr-x 7 User1  Group1   60K Sep 26 12:45 MME
drwxrwxr-x 8 User1  Group1   84K Sep 26 12:51 MSC
drwxrwxr-x 8 User1  Group1   36K Sep 26 12:51 IMS
drwxrwxr-x 7 User1  Group1   68K Sep 26 12:51 MMSC
drwxrwxr-x 7 User1  Group1   64K Sep 26 12:51 PGW
```

I need to know if folders CVBS, SMSC, SGW and PGW have been changed in last two hours.

Answer (score -1):

I assume `-cmin +120` does what you want, I didn't check it. Then according to [this serverfault thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/225798/can-i-make-find-return-non-0-when-no-matching-files-are-found), you can make `find` return false in case it does not match anything.:

```
if find folder_name -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -cmin +120 | grep -q '.'; then
    echo "Folder content is updated"
fi
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I have this to solve: 
In my root directory I have these directories:

drwxr-xr-x 2 User1  Group1 4.0K May 24  2013 current_archive
drwxrwxr-x 8 User1  Group1  4.0K Aug 21  2014 CELLS
drwxrwxr-x 2 User1  Group1 4.0K Aug 27  2014 TESTORA
drwxrwxr-x 5 User1  Group1  4.0K Jul 10  2017 TEST
drwxrwxr-x 8 User1  Group1  4.0K Sep 26 11:11 CVBS
drwxrwxr-x 7 User1  Group1  232K Sep 26 12:15 SMSC
drwxrwxr-x 7 User1  Group1   36K Sep 26 12:45 SGW
drwxrwxr-x 7 User1  Group1   60K Sep 26 12:45 MME

Comment: drwxrwxr-x 8 User1  Group1   84K Sep 26 12:51 MSC
drwxrwxr-x 8 User1  Group1   36K Sep 26 12:51 IMS
drwxrwxr-x 7 User1  Group1   68K Sep 26 12:51 MMSC
drwxrwxr-x 7 User1  Group1   64K Sep 26 12:51 PGW


I need to know if folders CVBS, SMSC, SGW and PGW have beed changed in last two hours.

Comment: Your code give me "Folder content is updated" for both old (CELLS) and new (PGW) folders.

Comment: Post the `ls` output into your question. Comments remove newline - it's unreadable.